# Much more/many more

Tags: uncountable-nouns, countable-nouns

I undestand we use **many more** when talking about things we can count, with countable nouns. And **much more** with uncountable ones. But I was wondering if there were cases where they could be interchangeable like:

"I have **much more** friends than you." For some reason I can't put a finger on, this sounds better than "I got **many more** friends than you" to me. At the same time, "I have **many more** friends living outside the country.", sounds better than using **much more** here.

And with the word **problems**, can either be used? "I have **many more** problems to deal with." .. "I have **much more** problems than you."

Comment: Technically, if using a countable noun such as _friends_ or _problems_, you should use **many more** instead of _much more_, but I hear them used interchangeably all the time. I probably would say _"much more friends"_ without even realizing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are not interchangeable in standard (correct) English. But that doesn't mean they are not used interchangeably.

Take a look at these:

> "There wasn't much people about that day." — Bram Stoker, Dracula.
>
> "Sir Launcelot will abide me and you in the Joyous Gard; and much people draweth unto him, as I hear say." — Sir Thomas Malory, Le Morte d'Arthur.

"much more" can be used with countable nouns for emphasis (in comparisons with other people) in colloquial speech or as a tool of emphasis for stunning writers (as the examples above).

So let's look at your sentence:

> "I have *much more* friends than you."

You can see that the emphasis is on the contrast between the two entities (speaker and listener) in relation to the number of friends. The contrast is what makes the sentences insulting, so by emphasizing the contrast, the sentence is more directed to its purpose. And because of this, it seems more appealing than *many more*.

> "I have many more friends living outside the country."

The phrase seems to be stating a condition, so there is no need to put emphasis anywhere. But if it was in this context...

> (Quarrel)
>
> Shia: I have many friends living outside the country and some told me the Corona is going to spread all over the world!
>
> Lia: You know what, I have *much more* friends living outside the country, and all of them told me that the virus is never going to be a global disease!
>
> Shia: I have *much much more* friends living outside the country then, 'cause I heard it from some!

The same goes with the last two sentences. But you already understood, no need to repeat it, right?

Comment: I don't quite understand -- "_**much more** friends than [someone]_" could certainly be insulting, but if you said "_**many more** friends than [someone]_", is that... less insulting? I feel like it wouldn't draw as strong of a reaction simply because "_much more_" in that context is more common.

Comment: Sorry, I was kinda ambiguous over there. Edited!